# Change view when using webBrowser to browse directories

Tags: c#, browser

imagine you are using webBrowser control to browse local file system, so it behaves like Explorer

`WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

wb.Navigate(@"c:\");`

Now it displays contents of c:\ directory. But I'd like it to **programatically** set the view mode to "Details" view and not to display whatever mode the logged-in user currently uses.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the documentation for the IShellBrowser interface:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775123(VS.85).aspx

You are probably going to have to find the IServiceProvider interface implementation on the web browser to get to this interface, and all of it is more than likely going to have to be done through COM interop.

Comment: I was able to find that interface, but I can't find any method either in MSDN documentation or on the internet that would change the view mode. I'll probably have to implement this on my own

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone with same req. Don't use WebBrowser Control, instead use Microsoft Web Browser control which is the actual IE control. (WebBrowser is just a wrapper on top of this and does not expose this object)

Once you have Microsoft Web Browser (say axWebBrowser1) added, navigate to a folder like...

```
axWebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\\");
```

After you make sure that navigation is complete (by catching NavigateComplete2 event), add the following code

```
dynamic oDoc = axWebBrowser1.Document;
oDoc.CurrentViewMode = 4; //4 for details view
```

To get a list of other views Modes.. check this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-folderviewmode

By the way, how to add Microsoft Web Browser control to Toolbox?
Easy, right click on tool box -> Choose Items... -> COM Components tab -> check Microsoft Web Browser.